# expandTitle(...) is not a function

Tags: jquery, code-reuse

I try to reuse this part but the console keeps logging this error. I have made sure that I do not have any typo mistakes in the function name.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...

    function expandTitle(selector) {
        let param = $(selector),
            paramOverlay = $(selector + '>.overlay');
        let overlayHeight = getOuterHeight(param),
            overlayWidth = getOuterWidth(param);

        param.css({
            'height': overlayHeight
        });

        param.hover(
            function () {
                paramOverlay.animate({
                    'width': overlayWidth
                });
            },
            function () {
                paramOverlay.animate({
                    'width': 0
                });
            }
        );
    };

    ...

    (function () {
        expandTitle('#viewPointTitle>h1')();
    })();
});
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: remove the last `()` from `expandTitle('#viewPointTitle>h1')()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `expandTitle('#viewPointTitle>h1');` only instead of `expandTitle('#viewPointTitle>h1')();` as adding `()` means that the first function `expandTitle` returns another function and then that returned function is called immediately. And since you do not return any function from `expandTitle` remove that `()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function expandTitle(selector) {
       console.log(selector);
    };

    (function () {
        expandTitle('#viewPointTitle>h1');
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is how `()` works when you return a function from the called function:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function expandTitle(selector) {
      return function test(){
       console.log('inner function log');
      }
    };

    (function () {
        expandTitle('#viewPointTitle>h1')();
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```